# How to save JSON from Vk.com API response to MongoDB?

Tags: json, django, mongodb, mongoengine, vk

I am trying to get list of wall post from Vk.com  using Vontakte, mongoengine, Django
Here is my view, where `wallposts = vk.get('wall.get', owner_id=237897731, offset=0, count=10)` is Vk.com API call:

```
import vkontakte
vk = vkontakte.API(token=access_token)
class VkWallPostListView(ListView):
    model = VkWallPost
    context_object_name = "vk_list"

    def get_template_names(self):
        return ["blog/vk_list.html"]

    def get_queryset(self):
        wallposts = VkWallPost.objects
        if 'all_posts' not in self.request.GET:
            wallposts = vk.get('wall.get', owner_id=237897731, offset=0, count=10)
            for wallpost in wallposts:
                wallpost.save()
            #wallposts = wallposts.filter(text__startswith='RT')
        tag = self.request.GET.get('tag', None)
        if tag:
            wallposts = wallposts.filter(tags=tag)
        return wallposts
```

Also in this view i am trying to save results of API call to MongoDB right after the actual call:

```
        for wallpost in wallposts:
            wallpost.save()
```

But in browser i see an error:

```
Exception Value:    

'int' object has no attribute 'save'

Exception Location:     c:\Users\JOOMLER\BitNami_DjangoStack\django_mongo_test\blog\views.py in get_queryset, line 109
```

If i remove this two strings for cycle all works fine and shows on the fly data from Vk.com in browser. But i want to save it for later use. So, i assume the problem is how to save JSON response to MongoDB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was simple and i am surprised that no answers:
i need to use raw Pymongo:

```
wallpost.save()
```

is not correct, because save django model with predefined fields

```
VkWallPost._get_collection().insert(vk_post)
```

this is correct - we use raw pymongo `insert`

Answer (score 0):

Well, did you see what do you have in **wallposts** variable?

Cause, I think, **error message** is pretty clear: in cycle variable **wallpost** you have **int** value. And, of course, trying to call **save()** will throw exception. May be, objects in **wallposts** have integer indices, do you think?

Try to print what you have in **wallposts**.

Comment: If i do 
vk_posts = vk.get('wall.get', owner_id=1519369, offset=0, count=5)
            for vk_post in vk_posts:
                print vk_post  
I got in console a number 1367 nd the items like this  
{u'likes': {u'count': 4, u'can_publish': 1, u'can_like': 1, u'user_likes': 0}, u'attachments': [{u'photo': {u'access_key': u'dff779d5b0ebfa8818', u'src': u'http://cs540104.vk.me/c540103/v5401039  .......    u'from_id': 71201089}